# cross compiling qt: Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cross-platform, cross-compiling

last week I recieved my brand new Colibri VF61 with the Aster carrier board from Toradex.
I followed Toradex's guide on how to prepare the board to cross compile with qt [here](http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-up-qt-creator-to-cross-compile-for-embedded-linux).

Everything from the tuturial went perfect, however I tried deploying my app and everything goes fine until I open the executable on my target device because I get the following message :

> error while loading shared libraries: libQt5PrintSupport.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I went to see if I had any Qt files in my target device at all, and there weren't so I went to my sysroot folder in my host device and I copied all the Qt files to my target device, (Qt5PrintSupport was there) but after I copied all the files in the exact same location as they where in my sysroot the same error keep appearing.

The files I copied were:

> LibIcal               Qt5Core               Qt5OpenGLExtensions   Qt5Svg
>   PulseAudio            Qt5DBus               Qt5Positioning        Qt5SystemInfo
>   Qt5                   Qt5Declarative        Qt5PrintSupport       Qt5Test
>   Qt53DCore             Qt5Designer           Qt5PublishSubscribe   Qt5UiPlugin
>   Qt53DExtras           Qt5Enginio            Qt5Qml                Qt5UiTools
>   Qt53DInput            Qt5Gui                Qt5Quick              Qt5WebChannel
>   Qt53DLogic            Qt5Help               Qt5QuickTest          Qt5WebKit
>   Qt53DQuick            Qt5LinguistTools      Qt5QuickWidgets       Qt5WebKitWidgets
>   Qt53DQuickExtras      Qt5Location           Qt5Script             Qt5WebSockets
>   Qt53DQuickInput       Qt5Multimedia         Qt5ScriptTools        Qt5Widgets
>   Qt53DQuickRender      Qt5MultimediaWidgets  Qt5Sensors            Qt5X11Extras
>   Qt53DRender           Qt5Network            Qt5SerialPort         Qt5Xml
>   Qt5Bluetooth          Qt5Nfc                Qt5ServiceFramework   Qt5XmlPatterns
>   Qt5Concurrent         Qt5OpenGL             Qt5Sql                libxml2

Inside /usr/lib/cmake

and:

> imports  libexec  mkspecs  plugins  qml

folders to /usr/lib/qt5

I have noticed that the problem may be that I dont have the  "lib" folder inside /usr/lib/qt5 however I don't know how to create it since it wasn't in my sysroot.

Summing up: I want to execute my app by cross compiling but the lib folder is missing and I don't know how to create it or link it.

Comment: Note that a Qt build cannot be moved to a different installation path. Whatever folder you use on the build system must be the folder used on the target.

Answer (score 0):

Having a library in the same path with the app using it doesn't necessarily mean that your app can find it. Follow one of the methods below;

- Install the required qt libraries into system's standard lib directory(e.g. /usr/lib/)
- Set environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to where your qt libraries exist. Convention is generally having a bash script setting it then launching your app) or
- At compile time, you set rpath variable to the location of qt libraries folder (-rpath for gcc)

Comment: The problem is I don't have any lib folder to link `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to. I need to build that folder and I don't know how to.

Comment: Maybe all that you are missing is "mkdir /usr/lib"? (if /usr exists). If /usr doesn't exist either, then precede it with "mkdir /usr". then just copy the library files in.